# Android NativeActivity and ARCore C lib: function "ArSession_create()" fails when called in a NativeActivity

Tags: android, android-ndk, arcore, native-activity

I'm trying to create AR session by ARCore C library inside a NativeActivity.
However, the function "**ArSession_create()**" always returns error code **AR_ERROR_FATAL (-2)**, but there is no crash expcet that the AR session is not created. The following is the code snippet:

```
// Get the Android activity by a global variable, which is recorded
// in the NDK glue library function "void ANativeActivity_onCreate()"
// by the function's first passed-in parameter
ANativeActivity* activity = _global_android_activity;

//Get the JNI Env for the current thread
JNIEnv* env = NULL;
JavaVM* vm = activity->vm;
int r = vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

//Create AR session
ArSession* arSession = nullptr;
ArStatus status = ArSession_create(env, activity->clazz, &arSession);
if (status != ArStatus::AR_SUCCESS)
    CONSOLE_PRINTF(L"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Failed to create AR session!, Result = %d", status);
else
    CONSOLE_PRINTF(L"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Succeeded to create AR session!");
```

Android Logcat error message:

```
04-12 22:06:10.084 24454-24473/com.omnigsoft.gameenginedemo E/third_party/redwood/base/jni_common/src/class_util.cc: Failed to find class com/google/ar/core/SessionCreateJniHelper using custom class loader.
04-12 22:06:10.085 24454-24473/com.omnigsoft.gameenginedemo E/third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/sdk/session_create.cc: Failed to load SessionCreateJniHelper class.
```

**I have confirmed that** I have done the following thing to enable AR for my Android native app in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

- minSdkVersion set to 24
- added permission "android.permission.CAMERA"
- added ARCore meta data: android:name="com.google.ar.core"

**I also have confirmed that** my device (Google Pixel XL) is able to run ARCore sample app "hello_ar_c" (from the ARCode SDK, built by Android Studio).

So the question is: why the function **ArSession_create()** fails?
Has anyone successfully use ARCode C library with NativeActivity? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: To confirm: you are not receiving an `ArStatus` that you can inspect?

Comment: From the code "ArStatus status = ArSession_create(env, activity->clazz, &arSession);", I can say that the fnction returns the value AR_ERROR_FATAL (-2) to status.

Comment: I guess we need to focus on the error message "Failed to find class com/google/ar/core/SessionCreateJniHelper" to find the answer. Anyone has idea about this error message?

Comment: Maybe relevant? Note sure if it applies to your scenario or not. https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/122

Comment: Hi stkent, I'm using visual studio 2015 to build my native android app therefore there is no Proguard involved in the building, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the reason so I'd like to answer the question by myself.

In order to use ARCore manually in an Android app with other IDE instead of Android Studio, we need to the following things:

1. Download the ARCore library package (.aar) from Maven repository
2. Add the ARCore's shared library "libarcore_sdk_c.so" into the app's APK package
3. Add the ARCore's java library "classes.jar" into the app's APK package

I did 1 and 2 but forgot the 3, therefore I got class-not-found error at run time.

There are more errors come out but at least I solved this problem.
It seems like using Android Studio for ARCore app development is the only comfortable way at present.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this exact error "Failed to find class com/google/ar/core/SessionCreateJniHelper using custom class loader" followed by "Failed to load SessionCreateJniHelper class", when embedding [arore-android-sdk/samples/hello_ar_c](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_c) sample over to the [android-ndk/native-activity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity) sample framework (while using Android Studio).

The issue in this scenario was the android:hasCode="false" directive in AndroidManifest.xml that the [NativeActivity sample adds](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/native-activity/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L14). Even if one does not have any Java code in a NativeActivity-based application, linking in ARCore does add Java code, so in that case android:hasCode="false" directive needs to be removed.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! I had issue with creating AR Session, and changing has_Code = true solved it!